# wp_nav_menu and fallback

Tags: menus

I am using this code to call any custom menu and display:

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'container' => 'none', 
    'container_class' => 'menu-header', 
    'theme_location' => 'primary', 
    'menu' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MenuName', true) ) 
); ?>
```

At the moment if there is no custom menu defined it falls back to the primary menu.

I am trying to edit this code, so if there is no custom menu then display nothing. Having no luck, doesn't help that I'm new to php and wordpress. I have searched online and tried a few other solutions. Knowing my luck it's probably something really simple.

If anyone could help me out, I'd appreciate it a lot!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Simply set it to a predefined core-function that returns `null` or `false`:

```
'fallback_cb'     => '__return_zero'
// or
'fallback_cb'     => '__return_false'
```

Answer (score 2):

the wp_nav_menu fallback is wp_page_menu() by default.  you think you could change the fallback to a null string

```
'fallback_cb'     => '',
```

or you could first test for the presence of a menu?

> if(has_nav_menu('primary')) wp_nav_menu('theme_location'  =>
>   'primary');

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. 

kaiser, I tried using the fallback but that didn't seem to work.

@helgatheviking, I couldn't quite figure out what to do with the if statement you posted :s

Do I wrap my original code in the if statement? Apologies for silly questions.

Comment: I figured it! This is the final code:

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
'container' => 'none', 
'container_class' => 'menu-header', 
'theme_location' => 'none',
'menu' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MenuName', true), 
'fallback_cb' => 'false'
) 
); ?>

thanks for the tips :)

Comment: `'fallback_cb' => 'false'` simply deregisters any fallback. @helgatheviking +1 btw :)

Comment: thanks kaiser, i learned something new from your answer re: __return_false . @jaffa786 - yes you could have wrapped your code w/ the IF statement

Comment: Quick additional note here- thanks to this thread, I realized that in order for the `'fallback_cp'` option to work at all, apparently one needs to also register `'theme_location'` (in my case, I set it to `'none'` as in @jaffa786's code in the comment above). Otherwise, in the absence of that parameter, it seems whatever you set for `'fallback_cb'` is ignored.